# VS 2010 MVC : program is still working without controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

Help! why the controller of my program is still working even though I already deleted all of my controller methods. I don't know what's happening, it's like the program became immortal.

Sorry, I'm still new to MVC.

here's my controller example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(login a)
{
    try
    {
        using (var c = new Entity.DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var b = c.accounts.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ID == a.cID && v.password == a.cpassword);

            if (b == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
         }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here's the login form in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.cID)

    @Html.PasswordFor(e => e.cpassword)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.cpassword)

    <p ><input type="submit"  value="Login"/></p>

}
```

I removed the login controller and when i tried loging in the program is still working

Comment: Its your lucky day that I am here. Because I am a wizard and I can fix code without even looking at it ;)

Comment: @CodingYoshi the master of all wizards.. Please help me how

Comment: it was a joke. You need to post some code so we can look at it and help you.

Comment: Im so sorry, do I have to post my code?

Comment: @Amits, Did you rebuild your your project after the deletion of controller???

Comment: @AlsamilMehboob yes,I already ended my sessions everything that is connected the controller and also I restarting my computer but still the program is working. It's like magic